# Cable network don't work propertly

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, networking

I have this problem during the last weeks so I'm going to detail it everyting I can. I'm sorry if there is unnecesary info here.

A few weeks ago I changed my home network. Before changes, I had a simple conexion to my PC and RaspberryPi via PLC from my router. At this point everything work perfectly.

Now I have this network at home:

- My old router (NETGEAR CG3110D) have wifi disabled and is working only as neutral modem (my conexion arrives as coaxial cable and that was the unique option I had).
- My new router (Archer C7 v2), has the Internet input connected to the
  output of my old router. It has the dualwifi enabled too.
- My PC and my Raspberry Pi 2 B are connected via Enternet cable direcly to my new router.

**Now my network info is**

Old router network

- Old router 192.168.1.1 , 255.255.255.0 (DHCP enabled)
- New router 192.168.1.3

New router network

- New router 192.168.0.1 , 255.255.255.0 (DHCP enabled and with enough addresses)
- PC 192.168.0.101
- Chromecast 192.168.0.102
- Printer 192.168.0.103
- RaspberryPi 169.254.2.123

My RaspberryPi connect well when my pc is disconnected. So if I connect my RaspberryPi first than my PC it works fine.
I tried adding a default gateway to raspbian and connecting manually (no dhcp), and it dont work.

*I crimped again a few times some cables and I bought a connection tester. I can say that all network cables are working fine.*
*RaspberryPi and routers software are all up to date.*

Comment: Did you config your RPi to use a fixed IP adress or did you use the default setting, IP adress given by a DHCP ?

Comment: How is the network configured on the RPi and the router? My thought is that this is more related to your router than the RPi.

Comment: Are you running DHCP servers on both routers? At any event this is not a Pi question, and you haven't provided enough information for anyone to solve your problem.